# Logging OpenVPN/PPTP connections

Tags: linux, vpn, logging, openvpn, pptp

I currently have a default setup of **OpenVPN and PPTP**. I was wondering how I can enable the most verbose logging of the services so in case of abuse we can track down who's IP did what?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html

sample-config-files/server.conf

```
# Set the appropriate level of log
# file verbosity.
#
# 0 is silent, except for fatal errors
# 4 is reasonable for general usage
# 5 and 6 can help to debug connection problems
# 9 is extremely verbose
verb 9
```

Answer (score 0):

with the openvpn option 'verb 9' you will get much more overhead than you need. take a look at this project  http://sourceforge.net/projects/ipt-netflow/

Answer (score 0):

For PPTP this might give some clues:

```
pon NAME_OF_TUNNEL debug dump logfd 2 nodetach
```